# Rails open xls(excel) file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

I have a file `b.xls` from excel I need to import it to my rails app

[image]

I have tried to open it

```
file = File.read(Rails.root.to_s+'/b.xls')
```

I have got this[image]

file.encoding => #Encoding:UTF-8

I have few questions:

1. how to open without this symbols(normal language)?
2. how to convert this file to a hash?

   File pretty large about 5k lines

Comment: Please use `Rails.root.join('b.xlsx')`. It is much nicer.

Comment: Have you tried to use some libs like [`roo`](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) ?

Comment: @Зелёный yes i tried `roo` it returns me an array,which is useless for me

Comment: `roo` has an option to returns a hash. [_If each is given a hash with the names of some columns, then each will generate a hash with the columns supplied for each row._](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo#querying-a-spreadsheet)

Comment: oh,nice didn't notice it

Comment: "it returns me an array,which is useless" - Also, it's not at all difficult to turn array of arrays into an array of hashes. It's literally 2-3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You must have array of all rows then you can convert it to some hash if you like so.

I would recommend to use a `batch_factory` [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/batch_factory).
The gem is very simple and relies on the `roo` gem under the hood.
Here is the code example

```
require 'batch_factory'
factory = BatchFactory.from_file(
  Rails.root.join('b.xlsx'),
  keys: [:column1, :column2, ..., :what_ever_column_name]
)
```

Then you can do

```
factory.each do |row|
  puts row[:column1]
end
```

You can also omit specifying `keys`. Then `batch_factory` will automatically fetch headers from the first row. But your keys would be in russian. Like

```
factory.each do |row|
  puts row['Товар']
end
```

If you want to hash with product name as key you can do

```
factory.inject({}) do |hash, row|
  hash.merge(row['Товар'] => row)
end
```